# Is there something wrong?

Tags: javascript, function

There is this part in my java script file... the code runs without this part but as soon as i add this, it stops working. I can't find any mistake.. can you tell me if there is any-

```
Function check(){
var verify = localStorage.getItem("answer");
if(document.getElementById("answer").value= verify){
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = Correct;
    var voda = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("some"));
    var airtel = voda + 1;
    localStorage.setItem("some", airtel);
    question();
} else{
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = Wrong... ;  
};
};
```

i have another function called question(){.....}; which i am calling in this function. I have a doubt in this part.

Comment: `"Correct"` and `"Wrong..."` for a start - they're strings. Anything else you would have to explain any errors you're getting in the console.

Comment: `Correct` and `Wrong...` have to be within quotes.

Comment: The Console of your browser's developer tools is your friend. `http://jshint.com/` is your friend. JavaScript is case sensitive. `function` doesn't begin with a capital letter. You've got at least three different kinds of error here.

Comment: `Function` should not be capitalized. If you're running this within a browser, the error log in your browser's Javascript console should give you the line of error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment instead of comparison here

```
if(document.getElementById("answer").value= verify){
```

Should probably be this instead

```
if (document.getElementById("answer").value === verify) {
```

There are other parts that aren't correct:

`Function` is not the right keyword for defining a function as you do, use `function` instead.

Also these lines:

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = Correct;

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = Wrong...;
```

The right hand needs to be wrapped in quotes:

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = 'Correct';

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = 'Wrong...';
```

As a suggestion, I would also recommend specifying the radix (or base) when using `parseInt`:

```
var voda = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("some"), 10);
```

Comment: That isn't enough to fix all the problems though

Comment: @Quentin Incomplete you are right, I updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have wrong if statement.
InnerHtml (wrong and correct) text should be in quotes.

Here is the correct one:

```
    function check(){
var verify = localStorage.getItem("answer");
if(document.getElementById("answer").value == verify){
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Correct";
    var voda = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("some"));
    var airtel = voda + 1;
    localStorage.setItem("some", airtel);
    question();
} else{
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Wrong...";  
};
};
```

Comment: Well, we don't know if it's _completely_ correct. There may be other non-typo errors like missing elements, or `question` doesn't exist...

Comment: Anyway I use Javascript console to catch all the errors.